# Firefox: edit HTML and see changes live

Tags: firefox, firebug

That's it folks, Firebug is officially discontinued and as of today, with Firefox v56, it is not working anymore. So the alternative is Firefox Developer Tools.

I tested it and it seems really weak when comparing.

My question is, when you inspect an element, and edit HTML, with Firebug, you could see the changes that you type *live* as you're typing it, but with the developer tools, you need to finish editing entirely before the changes are applied. Is there any way to make the changes appear live while you are typing them out?

Comment: In Firebug you can  edit the HTML directly by right-clicking a node and clicking Edit HTML... in the context menu. In the DevTools this option is also available via the context menu. There the option is called Edit As HTML. Only the _live preview_ of changes **is currently missing**

Comment: @Dubois Exactly, the very essential **live preview** is missing. Is there any way to activate it? Or maybe an alternative plugin that shows live preview of your changes?

Comment: the _live preview_ is tracked in [bug 1067318](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1067318) and [bug 815464](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=815464). I think you can find an answer there! There people whose got the same problem as you. And i think they may have got some solutions!

Comment: Thanks but both of those bug reports dates back in *years* and are not close to be resolved.

Comment: did you tried to find if there is an _add-ons_ (to download) which can activate the live preview yet?

Comment: please check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgyeFRVUC9E) if it can help. They are talking about  how to set Mozilla Firefox or other browser for Live Preview in Brackets code editor.

Comment: Brackets is a third-party addon right? My aim is to accomplish this with the Firefox dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in Firefox 56 there is no way to show the HTML changes live. You have to wait for [bug 1067318](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1067318) and [bug 815464](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=815464) to be fixed.

Comment: Are you referring to the two bug reports that are something like 5 years old? It will never be fixed.

Comment: I have confidence that they will get fixed at some point. Unfortunately, Mozilla obviously has other priorities at the moment, i.e. finishing the [Quantum project](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/quantum/). From my experience, some bugs are fixed very quicky, others take months or years, depending on priorities. I'd personally like to see this feature be implemented sooner than later, that's why [I pushed on this earlier](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1267303).

Comment: That is great. I had a look through your profile randomly and I can see that you are engaged in this more than I thought. Are there any plugins that offer live preview of editing beside Firebug? Maybe dev tools for other browsers? FIrebug could surely not be the *only* one with this feature?

Comment: Unfortunately, neither Chrome's, Opera's, or Edge's DevTools provide a live preview when editing HTML. I don't have a Mac, so I can't test Safari's tools. I only found one Chrome extension called [Canvas Flip: Visual Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-inspector-by-canva/efaejpgmekdkcngpbghnpcmbpbngoclc), which provides a live preview by allowing to edit the texts within the page.